# Scope of a local variable in a block

Tags: ruby, block, variable-assignment

If I have:

```
2.times do
  i ||= 1
  print "#{i} "
  i += 1
  print "#{i} "
end
```

I get `1 2 1 2`, whereas I was expecting `1 2 2 3`. Why does `i` lose its assignment when the loop starts over? It behaves as expected if the assignment occurs outside the loop, so I guess it has to do with scope, but I didn't realize loops have their own scopes. Can someone clarify?

*Update:* Thanks for the help on this. Part of my confusion stemmed from coming to Ruby from Python, which doesn't have block scope (I think).

Comment: is this for pedagogic purposes? because this kind of code is utterly unidiomatic...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the code below:

```
2.times do
  p defined? i
  i ||= 1
  p defined? i
  p "#{i} "
  i += 1
  p "#{i} "
end
```

Output:

```
nil 
"local-variable"
"1 "
"2 "
nil
"local-variable"
"1 "
"2 "
```

That means in each iteration a new scope is created,and `i` is known to that scope only; which is proved by `nil` and `"local-variable"`.

Now `i` is created outside of `block`, and see the output(no  `nil` comes):

```
i = nil
2.times do
  p defined? i
  i ||= 1
  p defined? i
  p "#{i} "
  i += 1
  p "#{i} "
end
```

***Output:***

```
"local-variable"
"local-variable"
"1 "
"2 "
"local-variable"
"local-variable"
"2 "
"3 "
```

To know more about `||=` look [`What Ruby’s ||= (Double Pipe / Or Equals) Really Does`](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html)

Answer (score 10):

I don't know what your expectations are based on. If you think what I think you think, it should be `1 2 2 3`. You can achieve that by declaring variable `i` outside of the block.

```
i = nil

2.times do
  i ||= 1
  print "#{i} "
  i += 1
  print "#{i} "
end
```

Then the block closes over that variable (closure) and uses it. Without closure, `i` is local to the block and is new every time.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the "loop" that has a scope. It's the block. Yes, a block is a local scope.

If you do not want a variable to be understood as local to the block, it needs to exist *outside* the block beforehand. Even just setting `i` to nil in a preceding line would do this.

(But your expectation of `1 2 3 4` will still not quite be met...!)

Comment: Actually, even just `if false then i = nil end` would be enough, but exactly *why* that is so would probably be too confusing to explain in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You can have some fun with it. Say for example you want to access the scope inside the block.

```
block = -> do
  x = "Hello from inside a block"
  binding # return the binding
end

p defined? x              #=> nil
x = eval "x", block.call  #=> #<Binding:0x007fce799c7dc8>
p defined? x              #=> "local-variable"
p x                       #=> "Hello from inside a block"
```

This is important because it allows developers to basically blow away the encapsulation of a block, and should be used with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you reinstanciate the variable `i` on each iteration and being reset to the value of one.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby loop like `x.times`  create local scope so variables introduce within this loop are local and will be destroyed after reaching the end of block. That's why you are not getting your expected result. 
In ruby if you want loop with out local scoping you can use `for` or `while` loop that does not create local scope but your local variable `i` will remain accessible after loop.

```
for j in (1..2)
  i ||= 1
  print "#{i} "
  i += 1
  print "#{i} "
end
```

print `1 2 2 3` as your expected result. Now if we run above loop aging it will give the result `3 4 4 5`. For extra information `while` and `for` work as same (scope less & print `1 2 2 3`) on the other hand `each`, `x.upto(y)` and `x.times` work as same (create local scope and print `1 2 1 2`)